# HTML Table to excel images have broken links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, excel

I have an HTML table and am trying to add a download to excel button to my website.

I have got the download working with this.

```js
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('main-table');

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }  
    else
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  
    return (sa);
}
```

And that's working other than the images and I know why the images are not working or I think I do.
In my table, I have the image like this

```html
<td><img src="./img/logo.png"></td>
```

But I need the full URL to make the links work when it goes into Excel is there a way I can use PHP to add the URL before the image tag?